# Why using static logger takes more time than not using it

Tags: java, static, slf4j, logback

I wrote following code to benchmark SLF4J (with Logback binding's) lookup performance:

```
public final class LoggerTest {

    private static final Logger staticLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTest.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        warmUp(50000);

        final int iterations = 1000000;

        final long t1 = staticExecutionTime(iterations);
        System.out.printf("Static time     : %d%n", t1);


        final long t2 = nontStaticExecutionTime(iterations);
        System.out.printf("Non Static time : %d%n", t2);
    }

    private static void warmUp(final int iterations) {
        executeStatic(iterations);
        executeNonStatic(iterations);
    }

    private static long staticExecutionTime(final int iterations) {
        final long s1 = System.nanoTime();
        executeNonStatic(iterations);
        final long e1 = System.nanoTime();
        return e1 - s1;
    }

    private static void executeStatic(final int iterations) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            staticLogger.trace("Do nothing!");
            staticLogger.debug("Do nothing!");
        }
    }

    private static long nontStaticExecutionTime(final int iterations) {
        final long s2 = System.nanoTime();
        executeNonStatic(iterations);
        final long e2 = System.nanoTime();
        return e2 - s2;
    }

    private static void executeNonStatic(final int iterations) {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            final Logger localLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerTest.class);
            localLogger.trace("Do nothing!");
            localLogger.debug("Do nothing!");
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in one scenario I used an static logger which is initialized during class-load time, and in another scenario I lookup the logger each time.

I was expecting using static logger be faster, but both scenarios almost took same time, and surprisingly *non-static scenario is usually a little faster*.

Can any body describe this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method

```
private static long staticExecutionTime(final int iterations) {
        final long s1 = System.nanoTime();
        executeNonStatic(iterations);
        final long e1 = System.nanoTime();
        return e1 - s1;
    }
```

is executing the wrong internal method :p

it should call `executeStatic(iterations);` and not `executeNonStatic(iterations);`

Correct it and you'll get a different picture :)

Comment: Thanks Farid, silly am I! But overhead is about 67 nano-second per lookup on my PC, which is little.

Comment: I'm getting a different result myself: static time = 8 ms, non static time = 49ms (6 times the static result), and non static time (when storing the logger in a non final variable) 52ms. note that nanotime relies a lot on the availability of high precision counters, correct jvm interfacing to the hardware,... i usually avoid nanotime measurement; its reliability is too much dependent on the environment.